# Can global variables be accessed from a thread within a new process?

Tags: python, multithreading

In the script's main thread, I setup a variable called `queue` and fill it with URLs. Then I create 8 processes using `multiprocessing.Process` and then those processes spawn 10 threads each using the `threading` library.

Within the thread worker (which was spawned by another process as per above), I have `global queue`.

Then will `queue.get()` act as expected? I've tried it and it seems to be okay during some tests and others not.

Question is, can global variables be accessed from another process and thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to understand what you are exactly asking. But there are two main questions here:

**Can global variables be accessed from another process?**

No, not without some form of inter-process communication, and even then you would be passing a copy of that variable to the other process. Each process has its own global state.

**Can global variables be accessed from another thread?**

Yes, a thread who lives in the same process can access a global variable, but you must ensure the safety of any memory that is accessed by multiple threads. Meaning, threads should not access writable memory at the same time as other threads or you run the risk of one thread writing to the memory while another thread attempts to read it.

**Answering Question Above**

If I understand the setup correctly, each of your child processes has their own global variable `queue`. Each of those `queues` should be accessible only to the threads that are spawned within that process.

Comment: The new thread is spawned by a new process aka can global variables be access from another process AND thread.

Comment: Threads who are spawned by separate processes do not have access to the same global variables. So if you spawned thread Ta in process Pa, and spawned thread Tb in process Pb, Ta and Tb would not have any sharable global state because they belong to different processes.